# move up a frame, debug R environment

Tags: debugging, r, frame

When debugging a function, I would like to move up to the parent frame and look at some variables there.  How do I do this?

Here is a sample:

```
f <- function() {
   x <-1
   g(x+1)
}
g <- function(z) {
   y = z+2
   return(y)
}
```

I then debug both functions using `debug("g")` and `debug("f")`.  When I end up in `g` at the `Browser>`, I would like to move back up to `f` to examine x.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In R terminology, you are wanting to investigate the parent frame of `g()`'s evaluation environment (i.e. the environment in which `g` was called).  The functions for doing that are documented in the help page for `?sys.parent`.

Once your browser indicates that you are `'debugging in g(x + 1)'`, you can do the following. (Thanks to Joshua Ulrich for suggesting `where` to help locate ones position in the call stack .)

```
# Confirm that you are where you think you are
where
# where 1 at #3: g(x + 1)
# where 2: f()

# Get a reference to g()'s parent frame (an environment object)
pframe <- parent.frame()
pframe
# <environment: 0x019b9174>

# Examine the contents of the parent frame
ls(env=pframe)
# [1] "x"

# Get the value of 'x' in the parent frame
get("x", env = pframe)
# [1] 1
```

**EDIT**: To understand the collection of functions described in `?sys.parent`, it's probably worth noting that `parent.frame()` is (basically) shorthand for `sys.frame(sys.parent(1))`. If you find yourself in an evaluation environment farther down a call stack (as revealed by `where`, for instance), you can reach into environments farther back up the call stack (say two steps up) by either `parent.frame(2)` or `sys.frame(sys.parent(2))`.

Comment: Typing `where` while in the browser seems like it would be helpful to determine how many frames back you need to go.

Comment: Thanks @Joshua for that very useful suggestion. I grabbed it straight from your comment and pasted it in at the top of the code block.

Answer (score 42):

You can use `recover` 
(it is often used to debug code after an actual error,
via `options(error=utils::recover)`,
but it can be called directly).

```
> f()
debugging in: g(x + 1)
debug at #1: {
    y = z + 2
    return(y)
}
Browse[2]> ls()
[1] "z"
Browse[2]> recover()

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: f()
2: #3: g(x + 1)

Selection: 1
Called from: top level 
Browse[3]> ls()
[1] "x"
Browse[3]> x
[1] 1
Browse[3]>
```

Comment: Very cool. It had never occurred to me that `recover()` could be called interactively. Sometimes I think I should just sit back and watch the rest of you answer all of the questions, and this sort of gem  is exactly why.

Comment: Nice! And to exit a call to `recover()`, type `c` then `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Just call `on.exit(browser())` when browsing `f`'s body and you'll return back to it after you're done with `g()`

See output copied from the console below :

```
> f <- function() {
+   x <-1
+   g(x+1)
+ }
> g <- function(z) {
+   y = z+2
+   return(y)
+ }
> debug("f")
> debug("g")
> f()
debugging in: f()
debug at #1: {
    x <- 1
    g(x + 1)
}
Browse[2]> on.exit(browser()) # browser() will be run in this environment just before we exit
Browse[2]> 
debug at #2: x <- 1
Browse[2]> 
debug at #3: g(x + 1)
Browse[2]> 
debugging in: g(x + 1)
debug at #1: {
    y = z + 2
    return(y)
}
Browse[3]> 
debug at #2: y = z + 2
Browse[3]> 
debug at #3: return(y)
Browse[3]> 
exiting from: g(x + 1)
Browse[2]> x # we're back to f so we can investigate x
[1] 1
Browse[2]> 
exiting from: f()
[1] 4
```