# R: Moving up and down the callstack (frames)

Tags: r, debugging

When debugging in R, I would like to be able to jump up and down the call stack (frames in R-lingo) to view and change the environment on the different levels.

Essentially I would like the functionality of the `dbup`/`dbdown` in debug mode from Matlab for those who are familiar. Together with entering debug on error (`dbstop if error` in Matlab and `options(error = recover)` in R) I find it very powerful for quick debugging.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796843/move-up-a-frame-debug-r-environment) question is similar, with two answers. Using `parent.frame` "reaches" into a parent frame but doesn't put the user in that frame, making it cumbersome to use (have to add `env=` argument to all commands). In addition, I haven't found any corresponding function to access lower frames (something like `child.frame`).
The `recover()` solution was very useful but seems to be limited to choosing frame once. Upon subsequent calls to `recover()` to change frame, it seems to bug out. I don't end up in the frame I choose.

Is there some functionality like this in R/Rstudio? If so, what is it?
Bonus points if the solution would make the Rstudio editor snap to the offending line of each frame upon switch to said frame
(like Matlab does).

Comment: `recover()` while debugging does what you want.  Repeated calls will add more frames to the list of choices (they look like `eval(substitute(browser...`), but the original frames should be at the top of the list.

Comment: Thank you, you are mostly right! It seems I tested recover poorly. One remaining problem; When I select 1 in recover to go to top level environment (script I am writing), I end up in some environment I don't recognise. Do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: I found out; choose `4: eval(ei, envir)` in list recovery prompts with. It seems like the higher levels are stuff related to running code that R runs outside the actual script one is writing

Comment: Nathan, would you like to write an answer that I can accept or should I?
Or is it more suitable to remove question because of near duplicate?